# Highlight function highlights words in words

Tags: php, regex, highlight

i've developed the following function to highlight search results names.

```
function highlight($text, $words)
    {
        if (!is_array($words))
        {
            $words = preg_split('#\\W+#', $words, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        }

        $regex = '#\\b(\\w*)(';
        $sep = '';
        foreach ($words as $word)
        {
            $regex .= $sep . preg_quote($word, '#');
            $sep = '|';
        }
        $regex .= ')(\\w*)\\b#i';

        $text = preg_replace($regex, '\\1<b>\\2</b>\\3', $text);
        $text = str_replace("</b> <b>"," ",$text);
        return $text;
    }
```

My problem is that if the text is "This is the end" 
and i'm looking for "this is" it will highlight like that: "th**is is** the end" because the word "is" is in "this", too.

Somebody know how to fix that?

My first thought was to only replace whitespace[whitespace] but that's not a good solution because the first word in a sentence got no whitespace at the beginning. :-(

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `\w*` fro the begining and the end of regex:

```
    $regex = '#\\b(';
    $sep = '';
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        $regex .= $sep . preg_quote($word, '#');
        $sep = '|';
    }
    $regex .= ')\\b#i';

    $text = preg_replace($regex, '<b>$1</b>', $text);
```

Comment: That highlight the Whitespaces cO: “This<b></b> is<b></b> The<b></b> end<b></b>”
EDIT: Sorry i've not see the changes in preg_replace. :-)

That fixed it - thank you very much

Comment: @Marv: keep your `str_replace`